# Treat each monitor as a distinct desktop

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, synergy

I had Synergy set up so that in order for my cursor to cross over into another computer, I had to double-tap the edge of the screen with the cursor.

I would like to replicate this behaviour within a single system with three displays attached. In other words, I would like to bind my cursor to the current display, and have it move to a neighbouring display only when I double-tap the edge. This would make corner buttons, like the start and show desktop buttons, easy to reach again, while (hopefully) enabling aero snap to the edges of every display.

How might I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to natively do this in Windows you would need some type of third-party software. Stardock seems to have a number of programs that might offer something like this. Take a look at http://www.stardock.com/products/windowfx/

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Autohotkey, for instance? I'm mainly concerned with binding the cursor to the current display.

Comment: All Autohotkey does is automate actions and bind them to certain key combinations. You are looking for something that detects where the mouse is and changes default Windows behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a third party soulution as suggested in the comments. Their are a few like [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) and the best of which i think [Display Fusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/).

[image: About]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]

There are many settings in Display Fusion that you are talking about, unfortunately these settings are not available in Windows natively without some third party application.

Hope this helps, 
MORBiD